# Centering cards in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

The question is pretty straightforward, I've a CardView in a RecyclerView using a GridLayout with 2 columns.

[image]

The colors are just to make easy to see the components...
white is the LinearLayout
blue is the RecyclerView
green is the CardView

I want the cards be centered in the view with some margin from the edge... but i couldn't achieve it doesn't matter what I do. (this is what I want, made on paint)

[image: this is what i want]

If it is not possible, i would be okay with the cards aligned to the edge with all margin left between then

[image]

HERE GOES THE CODE:

This is the CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/influencerCardSize"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/influencerCardSize"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/smallMargin"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal">
```

This is the RecyclerView

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/influencersViewHeight"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/smallMargin"

            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: try adding the CardView in a RelativeLayout & add an atrribute to CardView as android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" or android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Answer (score 0):

Try having you card view inside the Linear layout

**Like :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your RecyclerView looks good.

Then if you want only two card per row .. try using AutoFitGridLayoutManager for the recycler view

**Like:**

```
AutoFitGridLayoutManager layoutManager  =  new AutoFitGridLayoutManager(context, width);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

Comment: pretty sure AutoFitGridLayoutManager is an outside dependency

Comment: Yes it is an outside dependency .. but it is worth using when you are supporting orientation changes.. so that the alignment is maintained with ease

Comment: It is... i couldn't import it

Comment: Right, I wasn't bashing because it's an outside dependency, only pointing it out because you should add that dependency as part of the answer

Comment: can you tell me which api to import?

Comment: import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager